# how to add formatted string (for multiple filenames etc.) in tchar

Tags: c++, tchar

Like in win32 C++ we use to use following code if needed to add multiple files as 
file_name0.txt, filename1.txt, ...., filename30.txt etc.

```
char fname[20];
for i = 0 -> 30 {
sprintf(fname, "filename%d.txt", i);
}
```

How can we do the same with **TChar** since I need to read multiple files in this case too

thanks
Kashan

Comment: You can specify string literals to use wide chars (16bit) like this `L"filename%d.txt"`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ but that is wchar not tchar.

Comment: @BartlomiejLewandowski What's `tchar` at all by means of standards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
_stprintf( fname, TEXT("filename%d.txt"), i);
```

You will need to define fname as a tchar.